# Customise behaviour of a Grails environment

Tags: grails

I was wanting to run a custom environment called "local"...as in a local dev.  I would use the config (eg DB connections) of this before a war would be deployed to the "shared" development server.  But I noticed that it lacks the behavior of the standard Grails "development" Environment, such as Changes to a GSP were not available when you refresh the browser.

So this led me to wonder how do you change the behaviours of a custom environment?  How can you copy all the settings for "development" to another environment?

Comment: Wouldn't the '"shared" development server' fit better as the custom environment?

Comment: Thanks and yes and actually this is the path I now started down, but curiosity has now won me over...I need to better understand another part of Grails...what makes development env different exactly and how can I customise this if needed...

Answer (score 5):

You can enable reloading of modified gsp in a custom environment specifying the run-app flag:

```
-Dgrails.gsp.enable.reload=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the automatic reloading is environment dependent. If you execute `grails run-app`, reloading will happen regardless of which environment you run under. In other words, automatic reloading will happen for all of

- `grails dev run-app`
- `grails prod run-app`
- `grails test run-app`

On the other hand, reloading will not happen if you build a war using `grails war`, then deploy it. So reloading depends on how you run the app, not the environment. The easiest way to define a custom environment that is similar to dev, is to define a set of default configuration, then selectively override the settings for each environemnt, e.g.

```
//default config
myApp {
    userRoleName = 'ROLE_USER'
    adminRoleName = 'ROLE_ADMIN'
    dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd'
}

environments {
    // config overrides for dev
    development {
        myApp.dateFormat = 'yyyy/MM/dd'
    }

    // config overrides for local
    local {
        myApp.dateFormat = 'MM/yy/dd'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Don, what you are saying makes sense and that is how I thought it should work.  I just tried again and if I run "grails -Dgrails.env=local run-app"  or "grails -Dgrails.env=local dev run-app" reloading is not working (under Grails 2.0.1).  So running like that it should pickup anything in "dev" but override anything where I have defined a "local" - as you described above...and that is how it is working for config settings but the reloading seems to get lost

Comment: I have to agree with Steve - Grails reload functionality doesn't work for custom environments. GSP recompilation can be fixed by adding `-Dgrails.gsp.enable.reload=true` to the command line, but the *.grails classes are still ignored. Adding `-Ddisable.auto.recompile=false` didn't help. I'm using Grails 2.1.1